# Google maps doesn't show until I refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I was following these simple instructions in official documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Everything works fine when I open the site for the first time. Map shows normally. The problem is when I navigate to other parts of the site. After I return to the location where map should be, the map doesn't show.

Here is the basic structure:

```
<ul>
  <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "About",   about_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript inside "Contact":

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>

<h1>Contact</h1>
<p>
  Address & phone number
</p>

<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 35em; height: 35em;"/>
```

So, if I open the site on "Home" page and then navigate to "Contact", there is no map. But if I refresh the "Contact" site, map appears. What could be a problem?

Thank you.

**EDIT1:**

I tried to put my code inside ready function:

```
$.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx&sensor=false');

        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
```

But when I do it like that, code breaks at this line:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using Rails 4.

Comment: ok so its due to turbolinks, put google scripts in your layout to have a quick fix. BTW, I just released a new version of gmaps4rails, it could help!

Comment: @apneadiving - Where should I put google scripts? I put them inside views/layouts/application.html.erb but it still only works if I refresh 'Contact' page. If I open home page and click on 'Contact', there is no map. Map shows only when I refresh that page.

Comment: dont understand the issue then, sorry

Comment: @ZdravkoVajudin Please can you make a jsfiddle.net illustrating the problem at all?  You may just have to use the raw HTML generated by your rails app.

Comment: Is there a piece of code that refreshes it? Because you could just use that to refresh it as soon as it appears.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using Rails 4 with turbolinks enabled? If so, the `load` event will not fire when you move from the Home page to the Contact page – but hitting refresh fully loads the whole page, so the load event does fire. This would be consistent with the behaviour you're describing.

Try adding this at the end of your script block, **in addition to** the `'load'` line:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'page:load', initialize);
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't make any difference. I still need to refresh.

Comment: It may be that window's not the correct scope for the 'page:load' event. The jQuery $(document).ready and $(document).on('page:load') event listeners, as referenced by Akshat, will be suitable triggers – you can replace Google's suggested listener with the jQuery ones.

Comment: I tried many combinations but it doesn't work. I updated my question.

Comment: I remain convinced that your problem is allied to the use of turbolinks. I would try disabling turbolinks ([instructions here](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4)) and seeing if the map updates correctly. If it does, and you still want to use turbolinks, then reinstall turbolinks and update the javascript code that listens to events.

Comment: I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'event' of undefined`. Any ideas?

Comment: Worked great for me. I was previously using the [jquery-turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem as a fix but it had a nasty side effect of running all jquery `ready` code with each page load in turbolinks.

Answer (score 2):

Just provide a delay to the function that initialize the google map and it would work just fine.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  //code for initializing the google map
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the timeout to six seconds worked for me. The bigger the map the longer it takes, so gauge your timeout based on your map size.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what might be going wrong.  When you say you navigate to other parts of the site, are they all contained in one HTML file? Or perhaps they are loaded in dynamically with AJAX?  Try triggering a resize event on the map when it's not showing properly.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Alternatively this can be called after when you "navigate" to somewhere where it should be but isn't showing.

Comment: They are not all contained in one HTML file. The problem is that map disappears every time I click some other link. Only refresh of the site where is map shows the map.

Comment: Unfortunately, google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with your turbolinks, bind your all activities in one function and call that function on `document.ready` as well as at `document.page:load` event.

```
$(document).ready( PageSetupFunction );
$(document).on("page:load", PageSetupFunction );
```

Actually here document.ready will be called when you refresh the page. But page:load event will be called once you come to this page from another link.

Comment: I tried many combinations but can't get it to work. I put this code in ready function: $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx&sensor=false');

        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions); -- The problem is when I put that code, nothing works, even other Javascript functions which worked before don't work.

Comment: Though i haven't worked with google maps but i have faced same problem with google charts api. It seems that you are having some error in your javascript which stops all other script next to it from executing you must check it in your browser console

Comment: Yes, error is here: center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644). I don't know why is that line a problem if it's c/p from google.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this triggering the code after page is loaded using jQuery

```
$(document).on("pageshow","#contact",function(){
  initialize();
});
```